# What would be the best way to sort out a series of numbers (ids) in SQL

Tags: php, sql, math, logic

I have following series in the database:

```
9, 10, 10, 12, 12, 13, 15, 15, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
```

and I would like to make them all unique ( as they were supposed to be ). Can anyone please suggest what would be the best way to go with this issue?
Use of php code is okay (& preferred) but I can't do this manually as there are millions of rows in my database.
To make it a bit clearer, the resultant series should look like:

```
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
```

Comment: And the supposed SQL query used is ...... ?

Comment: What have you tried? also, some basic sql education: 1. if they're primary keys, they will be distinct anyway; all dbms's enforce that, 2. have you looked at the `distinct` keyword?, 3. have you looked at uniqueness constraints?

Comment: DISTINCT... ORDER BY....

Comment: I fail to see how that edit is better than original...A sequence or series is better presented inline

Comment: Make a `for` loop and loop from 8 to 31. Or an array `foreach`. put your queries within the loops and enter the data for the index

Comment: I haven't tried anything at the moment just trying to figure out a good logic. It was a bug in the application that I've fixed. On every first save the ids used to update to current maximum. Now, the data needs to be cleaned & ids need to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple easy ways to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT the_number_column
FROM your_table
ORDER BY the_number_column;
```

Or:

```
SELECT the_number_column
FROM your_table
GROUP BY the_number_column
ORDER BY the_number_column;
```

Minimal performance difference (at least with Oracle): http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:32961403234212

Comment: Thanks Elliot, if you notice carefully, the old duplicated id needs to be updated to a new id.
eg - 15, 18 , 18, 18 
needs to be 15 , 16, 17, 18

Comment: Would these IDs start over at 1 for the first row on the table? In your example, it starts at 9. Doesn't make too much sense. What if there was a gap in the numbers further down the list?

Answer (score 1):

You could use sql to select all records that are unique

```
select distinct column from table order by column;
```

Comment: Must have been writing it when you posted it